# Java MIDLET Manager.createplayer

Tags: java, midlet

I'm developing a Java mobile application, to play the URL "mmsh://****.asf" in that application, but i'm getting the exception "javax.microedition.media.MediaException: Cannot create a DataSource for: mmsh://****.asf".
My doubt is can i able to create a player for asf format or mmsh protocol?

```
    Player player = Manager.createPlayer("mmsh://****.asf");
```

Is there any other way to create a player?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different constructor:

```
Player player = Manager.createPlayer(InputStream is, String mimeType);
```

You might want to make sure the device supports the .asf format by calling:

```
Manager.getSupportedContentTypes(String protocol)
```